# Return the Record with the highest count of reference ids Active Record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, many-to-many

Find the country with the highest number of engineers

Engineers have a country_id referencing the table Countries, i found the answer through guess and check but i would love to know how to **return a single country with the highest count of engineers**, i've been looking for almost 24 hours now... HELP please

```
country = Country.find(34);
  country.engineers.count;
  => 9.
```

so far thats what i got

Comment: Read about how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: please give us an example of that table some code examples that you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it would be something like this on sql:

```
SELECT countries.*, COUNT(*) AS engineersCount FROM countries
INNER JOIN engineers ON engineers.country_id = countries.id
GROUP BY countries.id
ORDER BY engineersCount DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Slightly changed adaptation using AR:

```
Country.joins(:engineers).group('countries.id').order('COUNT(*) DESC').limit(1)
```

Refs:

[Can I do a max(count(*)) in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436820/can-i-do-a-maxcount-in-sql)

[How to find the highest number of times a value is in records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861575/how-to-find-the-highest-number-of-times-a-value-is-in-records)

Comment: wow that worked thank you so much, im totally gonna fail this code challenge for this job, as this is the first question, but there's much relief to get that one answer from a complex query.

Comment: @ChristopherDucote There is a great site to boost your sql skills called [pgexercises.com](https://pgexercises.com/). Try it out